# Removing spaces surrounding dashes in R

Tags: regex, r, gsub

I have a string of the form `[1] "James KNIGHT – S"`, I want this to read `[1] "James KNIGHT–S"` (generally with more text pre and proceeding). In my test case, I can use `gsub` or `str_replace_all` e.g.:

```
gsub(" - ", "-", x)
```

But in the string I have, this isn't working (both are `utf-8`). I'm trying to work out how to look for different types of dash (em, en, etc?), to ensure I can select (and remove) these later, and wonder if that's the issue here, or if I'm missing something else. I.e. I can't work out what's different between the test case and the file-data. Ideally any dash with whitespace around it and words would be collapsed to a "-".

Comment: That works! Thank you @akrun I don't really understand how that works...I need to read up on regex more

Comment: But, that was not specific.  It just removes the space before and after a nonspace character

Comment: @akrun re: e.g. that doesn't work rather than one where it does, the problem is I can't work out what the difference is between my test case and the file I'm trying to work with. As I say your suggestion does work, although actually I've just realised it collapses all the whitespaces.  I'll amend above (my text is of the form "B Knight - S")

Comment: Can you post the `dput` of the example that doesn't work?

Comment: try `gsub("\\s*([-–])\\s*", "\\1", x)`

Comment: @akrun the `dput` output just looks like `"James KNIGHT ? J"`

Comment: Thanks @AvinashRaj unfortunately that doesn't work either, spaces remain around the '-' character.

Comment: So, somehow it is not reading the character

Comment: You might need `\\p{Pd}` to match the `em` `en` dashes, but I can't test it as the original data you have may have different dash than the one you showed.

Comment: what would that look like @akrun ? I'm also trying to work out if there's a way to detect the (unicode?) character type/name (the `Unicode` doesn't seem to be helping)

Comment: I am guessing `gsub("\\s+(?=\\p{Pd})|(?<=\\p{Pd})\\s+", "", str1, perl=TRUE)`

Comment: @akrun that's worked, many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `\\p{Pd}` to match `em, en` unicode dashes.  Here, I use the regex lookaround to match one or more spaces (`\\s+`) that precedes or succede the dash and replace it with `''`.

```
gsub("\\s+(?=\\p{Pd})|(?<=\\p{Pd})\\s+", "", str1, perl=TRUE)
```

If required for consistency, all dashes can be replaced with a simple '-':

```
gsub("\\p{Pd}", "-", str1, perl=TRUE)
```